# PHP MySQL outputting two SQL Select Statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following two Queries that I would like to combine into one with the date being the first column. The problem I'm having is that the conditions of the subquery are different and the second query might not have a value for every month. I have been running them on different pages hence why the AS num_custs is the same on both.

I have tried a couple of different things with SQL but thus far have failed. My initial thoughts were to use UNION in the SQL but that didn't work. I think I am on the right tracks trying to do it in SQL rather than PHP.

First question would be which SQL command should I be using to achieve this?

Hope it all makes sense.

Query 1:

```
            SELECT * , COUNT( entity_id ) AS num_custs
                FROM (

                SELECT e. * , e.created_at AS abc123, o.status, o.total_invoiced, o.shipping_description, o.subtotal_incl_tax, MAX( o.created_at ) AS last_order_date
                FROM mg_customer_entity AS e
                LEFT JOIN mg_sales_flat_order AS o ON o.customer_id = e.entity_id
                WHERE e.entity_type_id =  '1'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'canceled'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'closed'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'fraud'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'holded'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'paypal_canceled_reversal'
                AND e.store_id
                BETWEEN 1 
                AND 2 
                AND o.total_invoiced IS NOT NULL 
                AND o.subtotal_incl_tax IS NOT NULL 

                GROUP BY e.entity_id
                HAVING last_order_date IS NOT NULL

                )sub_query
                GROUP BY YEAR( abc123 ) , MONTH( abc123 )
                ORDER BY abc123 DESC
```

Query 2:

```
            SELECT * , COUNT( entity_id ) AS num_custs
                FROM (

                SELECT e. * , e.created_at AS abc123, o.status, o.total_invoiced, o.shipping_description, o.subtotal_incl_tax, MAX( o.created_at ) AS last_order_date
                FROM mg_customer_entity AS e
                LEFT JOIN mg_sales_flat_order AS o ON o.customer_id = e.entity_id
                WHERE e.entity_type_id =  '1'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'canceled'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'closed'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'fraud'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'holded'
                AND o.status NOT LIKE  'paypal_canceled_reversal'
                AND e.store_id
                BETWEEN 1 
                AND 2 
                AND o.total_invoiced IS NOT NULL 
                AND o.subtotal_incl_tax IS NOT NULL 

                GROUP BY e.entity_id
                HAVING last_order_date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 91 DAY )
                AND last_order_date IS NOT NULL

                )sub_query
                GROUP BY YEAR( abc123 ) , MONTH( abc123 )
                ORDER BY abc123 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you wanted the date as first result, you can either specify all fields or just add it in front.

If you build the query in PHP you can easily inject the extra condition.

The condition will be inserted at the "%s" position in the [sprintf function](http://php.net/sprintf).

```
    // set $limit_order_date depending on the page

    $having = '';

    if ( true === $limit_order_date ) {
        $having = 'AND last_order_date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 91 DAY )';
    }


    $sql = sprintf("
        SELECT abc123,
               * ,
               COUNT( entity_id ) AS num_custs
          FROM (
            SELECT e. *,
                   e.created_at AS abc123,
                   o.status,
                   o.total_invoiced,
                   o.shipping_description,
                   o.subtotal_incl_tax,
                   MAX( o.created_at ) AS last_order_date
              FROM mg_customer_entity AS e
         LEFT JOIN mg_sales_flat_order AS o
                ON o.customer_id = e.entity_id
             WHERE e.entity_type_id =  '1'
               AND o.status NOT LIKE  'canceled'
               AND o.status NOT LIKE  'closed'
               AND o.status NOT LIKE  'fraud'
               AND o.status NOT LIKE  'holded'
               AND o.status NOT LIKE  'paypal_canceled_reversal'
               AND e.store_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2
               AND o.total_invoiced IS NOT NULL
               AND o.subtotal_incl_tax IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY e.entity_id
            HAVING last_order_date IS NOT NULL %s
                )sub_query
     GROUP BY YEAR( abc123 ),
              MONTH( abc123 )
     ORDER BY abc123 DESC",
        $having
    );
```

I hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what would happen if you had more than one $having? is that possible? Also how would you loop through each row?

Comment: You can have a select statement or multiple if statements collecting the 'having' conditions into an array `$having[] = " AND SOME CONDITION";` which you can combine with an `$having_string = implode('', $having)`